# Is ther anyone familiar with Erica Sadun's APIKit(app private api scanner)?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to use APIKit to scan my codes to detect if there is private API. apiscanner should run as

```
./apiscanner ~/Desktop/MyPath/myapp.app
```

I used command 'cd' go to the directory where apiscanner is. But if I call ./apiscanner ~/Desktop/MyPath/MyApp.app on terminal it reports

```
Last login: Sun Jun 13 07:22:07 on ttys002
  unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT trap
logout
```

Even if I copy the files apiscanner and doit to MyPath, then execute, I get the same problem. I think there is something wrong when I run apiscanner under Mac OS X.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Comment: Where do you download APIKit from? I lookead at ericasadun.com but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when 10.6 only binaries are run on an older system (10.5 or earlier).